# I have a French residence permit. Do I need a visa if I transit in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, french-language

As said in the title, I have a French residence permit and I would like to know if I need a UK visa if I transit there?

Thank you!

Comment: Visa requirements are usually decided on nationality, not residence. What's your nationality?

Comment: @Airsick visa exemptions sometimes depend on residency, as in this case, so it's not actually necessary to know the traveler's citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

The UK government has an excellent tool([click here](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no)) to see if you need a visa. I did a check on a citizenship that usually requires a visa to transit in the UK and will not be leaving the airport.

> **Exemptions**
>
> You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:
>
> - a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used
>     for travel to any country)
> - a residence permit issued by Australia or
>     New Zealand
> - **a common format residence permit issued by an European
>     Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland**
> - a resident permit issued by
>     Canada after 28 June 2002
> - a uniform format category D visa for entry
>     into a country in the European Economic Area (EEA) or Switzerland
> - an
>     Irish biometric visa (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’
>     section)
> - a Schengen Approved Destination Scheme (ADS) group tourism
>     visa where the holder is travelling to the Schengen country that
>     issued the visa
> - a flight ticket from the Schengen area, if you can
>     prove that you entered the Schengen area in the previous 30 days on
>     the basis of a valid Schengen ADS visa
> - a valid USA I-551 Temporary
>     Immigrant visa issued by the USA (a wet-ink stamp version will not be
>     accepted)
> - a valid USA permanent residence card issued by the USA on or
>     after 21 April 1998
> - an expired USA I-551 Permanent Residence card
>     issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998, with a valid I-797 letter
>     authorising extension
> - a valid standalone US Immigration Form 155A/155B
>     issued by the USA (attached to a sealed brown envelope) All visas and
>     residence permits must be valid.

I have highlighted in bold the one that would apply to you. Please check with your own nationality and circumstances to be sure on the link provided.